# RSPEC delivers a Name error on my vote spec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm getting a Name Error my votes that I don't quite understand. It's supposed to make sure that votes are only values of 1 and -1. I've been receiving a lot of NoNameErrors in my code pretty recently, so I'm wondering how I should go about fixing problems like these.

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    describe Vote do
        def valid?
            (@vote == 1) || (@vote == -1)
        end

    describe "validations" do

        before do
            good_v = Votes.new(value: 1)
            bad_v = Votes.new(value: -1)
            no_v = Votes.new(value:  2)
        end

        describe "value validation" do
            it "only allows -1 or 1 as values" do
                expect(good_v.valid?).to eq(true) 
                expext(bad_v.valid?).to eq(true)
                expect(no_v.valid?).to eq(false)
            end
        end
    end
 end
```

It doesn't seem to like the votes method that I'm using to create a vote. I wanted to use `good_v = @post.votes.create(value: 1)`, but I don't think that's working either.

```
clyde-browns-computer-2:bloccit clydiscope$ rspec spec/models/vote_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Vote validations value validation only allows -1 or 1 as values
     Failure/Error: expect(good_v.valid?).to eq(true)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `good_v' for #    <RSpec::ExampleGroups::Vote::Validations::ValueValidation:0x007fdd4ad44700>
# ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00397 seconds (files took 1.68 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:18 # Vote validations value validation only allows -1 or 1 as values
```

There should be a place where I should be defining something, but I not exactly sure what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors say that your codes make something wrong.

`before do` block set a local variable but in `describe` block can not use it.

Change that code to:

```
before do
  @good_v = Votes.new(value: 1)
  @bad_v = Votes.new(value: -1)
  @no_v = Votes.new(value:  2)
end
```

Then use these instance variable in test case.

Answer (score 2):

In rspec you should us the `let` directive:

```
require 'rails_helper'

class Vote
  def valid?
    (@vote == 1) || (@vote == -1)
  end
end

describe "validations" do

  let(:good_v) { Vote.new(value: 1) }
  let(:bad_v) { Vote.new(value: -1) }
  let(:no_v) { Vote.new(value:  2) }

  describe "value validation" do
    it "only allows -1 or 1 as values" do
      expect(good_v.valid?).to eq(true) 
      expect(bad_v.valid?).to eq(true)
      expect(no_v.valid?).to eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```